# Error When Building App with Maven Using Heroku

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my Discord bot using Heroku but everytime I deploy it, it gives me an error. The code works on local using IntelliJ Idea. Can anyone help me correct this error please?

Build log:

```
       [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
       [WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
       [INFO] Compiling 21 source files to /tmp/build_8fdb6208/target/classes
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [INFO] Total time:  9.237 s
       [INFO] Finished at: 2021-03-21T23:52:06Z
       [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
       [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project CalciteDiscordBot: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 15 -> [Help 1]
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
       [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
       [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
 !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
       We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
       please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
 !     Push failed
```

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>CalciteDiscordBot</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.target>15</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>
         
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
        <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0_168</version>
    </dependency>
    <repository>
        <id>jcenter</id>
        <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
        <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

You application requires Java 15 (`<maven.compiler.source>15</maven.compiler.source>`) so you need tell Heroku you want that specific Java version (instead of the default one)

In the root folder place a file system.properties:

```
java.runtime.version=15
```

Comment: I made a system.properties file and changed to java.runtime to 15 since I'm using JDK 15 right now and it builds successfully. But if I click "View" below "Deploy to Heroku" in the "Manual deploy" section, a page pops up with this: [link](https://imgur.com/a/PYetfF6). The application also does not function. Can you further elaborate for me please?  Here are my build logs: [link](https://pastebin.com/nvL5bvy4).

Comment: See `Procfile declares types -> Worker` which means it is a background thread. If you need to access it from the web you need to define a `Web Dyno`, using a Procfile

Comment: Oh, sorry I misunderstood what "View" means. I thought that's how you view your application logs but I was wrong(sorry). The build works but once I looked in logs from `Resources -> More -> View Logs`, it says this: [link](https://imgur.com/a/A7STyWb). I'm supposing this means classes are not imported correctly, is there a way to fix that?

Comment: It is best if you add the logs (from Heroku) as text in the question. It looks like a compilation error (more than a dependency)

Comment: Oh I'm very sorry. Here's the build logs: [link](https://pastebin.com/zGeFBifX). And here's the `Resources -> More -> View Logs` logs: [link](https://pastebin.com/CT8U954p) (also I did regenerate the bot token since it was in the logs).

Answer (score 0):

Someone just helped me with this issue yesterday your Maven POM specifies that you want Java 15, but the Java version installed cannot handle compilation for 15. So, add a system.properties file to your application root with the following contents and build again:

```
java.runtime.version=15
```